# Average If No Zeros

Tags: excel, if-statement, average

I have a table of data (below) where "W"='Wins' and "T"='Target'. Each category is based on a win-type.

The objective is to calculate an average "Score" in the right-most column across all categories based on the person's goals. Two observations: (1) For instances where "W"=0 and "T"=0, this category should be ignored in the average calculation--both in the numerator and denominator; (2) for instances where there is a win but no target (e.g. Bob's Category 7) only the win should be counted--i.e. Bob would have 200% for Cat 7

I took a shot at it, seen in image below, but kept getting #VALUE! message.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use Countif(F5,"<>0") instead of Countif(F5,"<>" &0)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what your are looking for. Could you work on your description?

Comment: The reason you are getting the error is you have an output of the IF formula of `""` which is a text and can not be added.  Change it to `0`.

Comment: What is the expected output for Sally?  I think I have something but want to ensure I figured correctly.

Comment: @ScottCraner--the expected output for Sally is 50%. In Cat 1,2,5, and 7 she got 50%,50%,0%, and 100% to goal respectively. This averages to 50%.

Comment: @VBAPete--I did try that and I'm getting the same result.

Comment: @ScottCraner--the issue is clearly the numerator. Each Category's IF statement works independently but when added together I'm getting the #VALUE! error. Any thoughts here?

Comment: Did you try replacing the `""` result with `0`?

Comment: @ScottCraner That solved it. Could you post the solution so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1):

In your formula, the `""` in the IF() functions resolves to empty text and cannot be added without an error.

So change all the `""` to '0'

---

Or you can use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(SUM((MOD(COLUMN(F5:R5),2)=0)*IFERROR($E5:$Q5/F5:R5,E5:Q5))/SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(E5:Q5),2)=1)*(F5:R5<>0)),0)
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: @sqlbg did you try the array formula?